# How to groupby and sum a criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below

```
FAMILY   TYPE   REMARKS
A        A1     Valid
A        A1     Invalid
A        A1     Invalid
A        B2     Invalid
A        B2     Valid
A        B2     Valid
```

How should I use `groupby` to make it look like

```
FAMILY   TYPE   VALID   INVALID
A        A1     1       2
A        B2     2       1
```

I tried

```
df['VALID'] = df.groupby('TYPE')['REMARKS'].apply(lambda remark: remark == 'Valid')
```

but the result is not grouped into 2 rows, how can I do that?

Comment: `pd.crosstab([df.FAMILY,df.TYPE],df.REMARKS)
`

Comment: ```pd.crosstab``` got the job done with ```reset_index()```, post it as an answer with some explanation so I can accept your answer

Comment: OK , done with that~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do `crosstab` + `reset_index` , it will count by two column FAMILY and TYPE over REMARKS

```
df=pd.crosstab([df.FAMILY, df.TYPE], df.REMARKS).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

- Using [`pandas.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```py
dfg = df.groupby(['FAMILY', 'TYPE', 'REMARKS']).agg({'REMARKS': 'count'}).unstack(level=2)
dfg.columns = [n[1] for n in dfg.columns]  # get rid of multi-level column name
dfg.reset_index(inplace=True)

# display(dfg)
  FAMILY TYPE  Invalid  Valid
0      A   A1        2      1
1      A   B2        1      2
```